# Passwordless public key is not working

Tags: ssh, password, public-key

this is my fist help ask here despite being a daily reader in order to learn.

I am working on a Unix environment (both Solaris and Aix servers) and my public key suddenly stopped working after months. I tried to re-create the key but it is still not working, here are the steps that I have performed:

```
cd
cd .ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa (input nothing on 3 prompts just as did before)
cat id_dsa.pub > authorized_keys
```

After that I did send all files to ~/.ssh at the desired server and validate that it was there. And it did not work.

I did a troubleshoot and: 1. Permissions are alright: .ssh dir is 700 ; authorized keys is 600 (I tried with many permissions). 2. sshd_config has only this entries:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
PermitRootLogin yes
PrintMotd yes
PidFile /etc/ssh/sshd.pid
Banner /etc/issue
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server
```

I have tried to re-create these keys multiple times... Also, I have tried to create RSA key and authorized_keys2, none worked. The curious is that it was working before with this same configs. SSH services as other Unix tools are administrated by a System Admin on this environment. Here is my ssh -vv output so that you can help me out:

```
/home/felipe/.ssh$ ssh -vv target_server
OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to target_server [10.22.6.26] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/felipe/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/felipe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/felipe/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.9p1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 126/256
debug2: bits set: 492/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'target_server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/felipe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 477/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/felipe/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/felipe/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/felipe/.ssh/id_dsa (0x866d380)
"THIS SYSTEM IS AMERICAN EXPRESS (AXP) PROPERTY.
THIS SYSTEM IS RESTRICTED TO AUTHORIZED INDIVIDUALS FOR BUSINESS PURPOSES.
INDIVIDUALS SHOULD NOT HAVE AN EXPECTATION OF PRIVACY WHEN USING THIS SYSTEM.
INDIVIDUALS RESPONSIBLE FOR UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS OR INAPPROPRIATE USE RESULTING
IN DAMAGES TO AXP OR OTHERS MAY BE SUBJECT TO CIVIL OR CRIMINAL PROSECUTION. "
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/felipe/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/felipe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /home/felipe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
felipe@target_server's password:
```

What I need is login into the servers without being prompted the password.

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: everytime you run `ssh-keygen` you are creating a public and private key pair, each related to each other, so you are not recreating your old public key. You need to move the newly created public key to the target server with `ssh-copy-id` for example (will prompt for server password)

Comment: I hope you are not copying your private key to the server as indicated by "copy all files to server" comment.  That's not what you want to be doing.  You copy the public key to the server by adding it to the authorized key file on the server end (not the client end).  As suggested by LinuxDevOps use ssh-copy-id if you have it available.

Comment: Well sooner or later all files would be copied on this environment as the filesystems are replicated daily. I have done exactly above mentioned steps with my mate's id and it worked.. It must be something with my id.. :(